# mount options ignored - debian 11 bullseye on raspberry with ext. usb drive

Tags: debian, mount, fstab, systemd-mount

I'm trying to mount an external usb drive to raspberry pi 4b with debian 11 bullseye.
Whatever I've tried so far to set mount options gets ignored.

```
/etc/fstab
UUID="9f32de87-6800-4585-a5c5-e6a3946ba2bb" /data ext4 defaults,nofail 0 0
UUID="9f32de87-6800-4585-a5c5-e6a3946ba2bb" /data ext4 rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async,nofail 0 0
PARTUUID=20df08a4-01 /data ext4 rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async,nofail 0 0
```

```
systemd mount unit
root@srv:/etc/systemd/system# cat data.mount 
[Unit]
Description=Mount /data with systemd

[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-uuid/9f32de87-6800-4585-a5c5-e6a3946ba2bb
Where=/data
Type=ext4
Options=rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async,nofail

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
mount command

root@srv:~# mount -t ext4 -o rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async,nofail /dev/sda1 /data
```

Output is always:

```
root@srv:~# mount -l | grep data
/dev/sda1 on /data type ext4 (rw,relatime) [data]
```

I know that most of the options are in the ext4 defaults mount option included, but also other options I tried are completely ignored.

Any hints how to do this? Any constraints with USB drives here I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async`, `suid`, `dev` and `exec` are the default states for an `ext4` mount, so only the non-default options (`sync`, `nosuid`, `nodev` and/or `noexec`) may be displayed.

`auto` and `nouser` affect mainly the `mount` command itself, and these are also the default states for these options. Normally all `/etc/fstab` entries that are not specifically marked with a `noauto` option will be mounted if/when `mount -a` is executed; once the filesystem is mounted, the `auto`/`noauto` option has already fulfilled its purpose and so there is no reason for the kernel to track it.

If `user` was specified, the `mount` command would have to keep track who mounted the filesystem (classically in `/etc/mtab` if it's a regular file; nowadays in `/run/mount/libmount` instead) as only root or the user who originally mounted the filesystem will be allowed to unmount it. But with `nouser`, the default classic Unix behavior of "only root can mount/unmount filesystems" prevails.

Out of all these options you've specified, `nofail` is the only non-default one, and it also only affects the the mounting process, causing it to not report an error if this filesystem cannot be mounted. Once the filesystem has been successfully mounted, the kernel has no reason to track the state of that option.

The reason the `rw` and `relatime` options are explicitly displayed is essentially historical: showing the `rw`/`ro` state explicitly is a long-standing practice, and `relatime` highlights the fact that the handling of the `atime` timestamp is not done strictly the classic Unix way. The other alternatives for `relatime` would be `noatime` (which can cause problems with e.g. the classic way to detect if you have unread email or not in `/var/mail`), and `strictatime` which would enforce the classic Unix behavior (and cause lots of mostly-unnecessary small write operations, harming SSD life and preventing disks from going into power-saving states). `relatime` has been the default since kernel version 2.6.30.

So your mount options are not actually getting ignored: you are just specifying a set of options that is essentially equivalent to the default way to mount the filesystem.

Comment: Thx to you, I think then nofail is also a default option and I just haven't found (seen?) this in the documentation. I tried some non-default options listed above and in fact they are now displayed correctly.

Comment: `nofail` is an option that only makes a difference *when a mount attempt fails* - so for things that have already been successfully mounted, there is no need to track it. So it only matters for the `mount` command, not for the kernel. `nofail` is definitely not the default in any distribution I know: you will see it for yourself if you configure an USB-connected disk in `/etc/fstab` without `nofail` and then attempt to boot with the USB disk unplugged: the system will be stuck in emergecy text-only mode, waiting for the administrator to fix the missing disk.

Answer (score 0):

to get all the mount options printed do the follwing when the mount point is mounted:

```
grep '/data' /proc/mounts
```

as to me it seems that mount options are OK just the methond to check them may not be correct.